# Reliable and quality jQuery debugger

Tags: jquery, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, firebug

I have tried Firebug for Firefox for debugging my jQuery code, but this tool fails on my Firefox. Then I tried the built-in DevTools debugger in Chrome and it also does not work correctly on my Chrome - it doesn't show all jQuery files the project contains, only some of them. Do there any other tools exist for jQuery debugging? I need to look inside jQuery files in real time and check their functionality.

Comment: The Chrome DevTools IMO don't have explicit support for jQuery (or any JavaScript library in general). Firebug has support for inspecting jQuery events through its [*Events* side panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Events_Side_Panel), but what do you mean by Firebug "fails on Firefox"?

Comment: It means it does not work properly on my computer. When I use Firebug it block Firefox browser window. I can work with Firefox only when switch off or uninstall firebug.

Comment: So you mean it hangs the browser, so it doesn't react to clicks or input anymore? Then make sure you have the [latest version of Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/) installed. If it's still an issue and you have a reproducible test case, you should [create a bug report](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/new) for it (if there's [not already one](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues)).

Comment: Chrome now has support for any library event listeners (including jQuery by default) to be handled like FireFox does now. Allowing you to get back to the *true* listener handler instead of the frameworks manager. However, the primary question is still vague. What *exact* functionality are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The Firefox DevTools allow you to inspect jQuery events and set breakpoints on the event handlers:

[image: jQuery events in Firefox DevTools' *Inspector* panel]

To see those event handlers you need to click on the 'ev' icon besides an HTML element. When you then click on the pause icon (indicated by the to vertical stripes '||') at the left side within the tooltip, you switch to the *Debugger* panel where you can set a breakpoint for the related function.

More information about this can be found at the [Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_event_listeners).